# Dockerize Breeze NextJS Project

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile, laravel-breeze

I want to dockerize my breeze-next project. I have designed the website completely and it works fine while running it via `npm run dev` and `php artisan serve`.

However I could not successfully dockerized the project as I am lost at what should I do. Could you advice me on what should I do?

Thanks :)

I've tried to dockerize my breeze-next project(Laravel,Nextjs). But I don't know what to do exactly.